# Why won't VS 2010 Correct Indentation when errors exist in my code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have noticed that Visual Studio 2010 (C#) in contrary to eclipse, will only correct indentation if your code is free of errors, I was wondering if there is a way to make VS still correct the indentation when errors are present.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that in the case of structural errors, Eclipse will occasionally generate incorrect indentations, so at some point you'll need to correct the indentation again regardless. It's not that VS *can't* do it, it's that it *won't* do it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, the parser is unable to parse the code, as it contains errors.

This means that it cannot pass the code information to the layout engine, as the parsing failed.

So, the code layout engine (which is what corrects indentation etc) doesn't work when you have errors in your code.

The way to make it work is to correct the errors...

Comment: @Steinfeld - don't know. It might be using a different mechanism than a full code parser for layout.

Comment: @Steinfeld: It is often possible to process incomplete/incorrect code with a simple heuristic to decide how to indent the text. This approach can be quite effective, and is probably what Eclipse is doing. Visual Studio uses a different approach: it holds a sophisticated Code Element model of your program, and it uses this to efficiently do lots of useful things (syntax highlighting, intellisense, refactoring, editing, etc) including the very simple task of indenting. The code model makes these easy to do. The down side is that the model can only represent code that is correct.

Comment: So to indent incomplete code in VS, you need a simple heuristic-based indentation extension, rather than using the built in system. Or you need to edit the code enough to make it syntactically correct so that the code model can represent it.

Answer (score 0):

No. Certain error are tolerated, such as undefined variables, but if any structural errors are hit, the auto indentation aborts. There is no way to change this.